# How does SELECT INTO works with SAS

Tags: select, sas

I'm new with SAS and I try to copy my Code from Access vba into SAS.
In Access I use often the `SELECT INTO` funtion, but it seems to me this function is not in SAS.

I have two tables and I get each day new data and I want to update my table with the new lines. Now I Need to check if some new lines appear -> if yes insert this lines into the old table.

I tried some Code from stackoverflow and other stuff from Google, but I didn't find something which works.

```
INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE T
VALUES (GRVID = VTGONR)
FROM NEW_TABLE V
WHERE not exists (SELECT V.VTGONR FROM NEW_TABLE V WHERE T.GRVID = V.VTGONR);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose of using the VALUES keyword is in your example. PROC SQL uses VALUES() to list static values.  Like:

```
VALUES (100)
```

SAS just uses normal SQL syntax instead.  See for example: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php

To specify the observations to insert just use SELECT.  You can add a WHERE clause as part of the select to limit the rows that you select to insert.  To tell INSERT which columns to insert into list them inside () after the table name. Otherwise it will expect the order that the columns are listed in the select statement to match the order of the columns in the target table.

```
insert into old_table(GRVID)
  select VTGONR from new_table
  where VTGONR  not in (select GRVID from old_table)
;
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but now I get a big error: ERROR: You cannot reopen old_table.DATA for update access with member-level control because 
old_table.DATA is in use by you in resource environment SQL (2).
ERROR: PROC SQL could not undo this statement if an ERROR were to happen as it could not obtain exclusive access to the data set. 
       This statement will not execute as the SQL option UNDO_POLICY=REQUIRED is in effect.

Comment: Normally I would do such an action in two steps. Create a table with the data to insert. Then insert the data.